# Docker: failed to open TCP connection to localhost:12345

Tags: mysql, ruby, api, docker, docker-compose

my problem is that I currently cannot login to my web ap that's running on docker. My docker-compose consists of my rails app, a mysql db, a restful api and a reverse proxy (someone recently just helped me out with this!). Everything is running fine currently (or at least I think so) and I can even test my api endpoint by going to localhost/api (and I see my doc for the api).

Problem is, when I login, it goes throug the restful api but I get an error as follow :

```
Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:12345 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 12345)
```

I've tried to expose the port in the docker-compose, but it didn't work. Here are the important files :

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  app:
    image: 'test/testapp:first-test'
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_USER: root
      DB_NAME: test_dev
      DB_PASSWORD: root
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 3306
      RAILS_ENV: development
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/test_app
    networks:
      test-network:
        aliases:
          - app

  api:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: 'test/testapi:first-test'
    ports:
      - "12345:12345"
    expose:
      - "12345"
    volumes:
      - .:/test_api
    networks:
      test-network:
        aliases:
          - api  

  reverse-proxy:
    depends_on:
      - app
      - api
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes: 
      - $PWD/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      test-network:
        aliases:
          - reverse-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_dev
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - .:/test_db
    networks:
      test-network:
        aliases:
          - mysql-db
        
networks:
  test-network:
```

nginx conf

```
# This is a default site configuration which will simply return 404, preventing
# chance access to any other virtualhost.

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # Frontend
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://hubsite:3000; # same name as network alias
    }

    # Backend
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://hubapi:12345/;  # <--- note this has an extra /
    }

    # location = /404.html {
    #     internal;
    # }
}
```

Now this is very "alpha", I'm pretty sure my volumes are all wrong and I should "link" my services altogether.

If anyone has information on this, I'd very much appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: Which component is producing that error message?  Nothing you've shown here would make an outbound connection to `localhost:12345`.

Comment: That would be the api service. Docker apart, if I start my go api on port 12345 and my ruby app on port 3000, I can login perfectly fine so long as the api is currently running!

Comment: (In terms of Docker constructs, you can safely delete the `volumes:` for the `app` and `api` containers [and run the code that's built into their images], the one `expose:` setting [it does nothing], and all of the `networks:` blocks [Compose provides a `default` network for you].  "Links" are an outdated Docker concept and there's no need for them any more.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the network environment you get by default.)

Comment: I see, but would that really fix my problem? I'm also wondering about something... When I make changes like that just to my docker-compose, am I supposed to follow a specific procedure to make sure the changes take effect? I currently just do docker-compose down before doing up afterwards. Thank you very much for all the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: It sounds like there's some code somewhere in your system that's trying to call the `api` container with the wrong host name (`localhost` and not `api`).  If you can find and fix it, `docker-compose build; docker-compose up -d` will rebuild your images and restart what needs to be changed; you don't need to manually run `down` usually.

Comment: @anothermh Yeah kind of, like David Maze suggested, there's probably somewhere where I mention localhost as my host, but I can't find it lol... Thanks for the link, I appreciate it :)